# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence vendor-es2015.js:43770

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing my Ionic/Angular app, and I'm running into the following error when I try to log in through back-end login api. Any ideas as to why? I googled it, but I could find any relevant info, the issue still remains. What causes this error?

```
vendor-es2015.js:43770 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
    at resolvePromise (polyfills-es2015.js:4147)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills-es2015.js:4104)
    at polyfills-es2015.js:4208
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.js:3741)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor-es2015.js:73623)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.js:3740)
    at Zone.runTask (polyfills-es2015.js:3518)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills-es2015.js:3909)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills-es2015.js:3819)
    at invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.js:4953)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
Please describe your question in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual task you want to accomplish, add you erroneous code snippet and what all resolutions you actually tried already to eradicate the issue.
Make a note to add corresponding tags and format your code before pasting here.
For more details, visit StackOverflow's guidelines including https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the cause of the issue. It's due to an error code returned by a back-end api call. After getting rid of the error code, the login functions well.